# How to reset the phone no. field that using the library NgxIntlTelInput?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am using the library NgxIntlTelInput for phone no validation.

I am able to reset all fields. I am unable to reset the phone no. field after submitting.

I tried using:

```
form.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

**The library isn't working like it should. form.reset() does reset the value but it does not clear the text in the underlying text input field.**

You will have to implement a reset function on your own. Give the phone number field a new id 'phone'. When you click the reset button call this function. I'm assuming you have followed the library documentation and the formGroup is named 'phoneForm'. Here is the demo from the github page of the library: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Try the solution here to confirm that it works.

```
reset(){
this.phoneForm.reset();
let phone = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('phone');
phone.value='';
```

}

Comment: Assigning an "ID" to the component does not seem to work, because it has a nested input which houses the value that is shown. I found this this works for selecting it: `document.querySelector('[type="tel"]') as HTMLInputElement;`